# 'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, easy-install

I couldn't run easy_install, even as setuptools are already installed. By the way, I could see the easy_install.py file under the ...\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command directory but there is no easy_install.exe file under .../Scripts directory. So the problem is not about PATH not added as there's no .exe to be found.

- setuptools 58.0.4
- python 3.8.8
- Windows 10

I wonder is there a way to directly invoke the easy_install.py to install .egg package?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Python lost `easy_install` at version 3.7. Forget about it, use `pip`.

Comment: @phd are you sure? how to install from local .egg file then?

Comment: Either downgrade to a Python version in range 2.7-3.7. Or forget about eggs, use wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to invoke `easy_install` from within a python script (credit to GitHub user @emailweixu [source](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/2544#issuecomment-916434748)).

```
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup( script_args = [ '-q', 'easy_install'
                         , '-v', 'PATH_TO_YOUR_EGG_FILE'
                         ]
         )
```

Note that this hacky solution is not going to work in the future, when `setuptools` removes `easy_install` from its code package altogether.